# Bulk AdWords audience creation via API with including/expluding multiple pagePaths

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

My goal is to use data from Google Spreadsheets as parameters for bulk creation of AdWords Remarketing Audiences from Google Analytics stats data.

My code is based on this [article](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Advanced-Features/AdWords-Script-Bulk-Remarketing-Audiences-Creation/td-p/643297#).

API connection seems to be working. Audiences are being created but I have an issue with specifying segment parameters that should include/exclude audience based on the ga:pagePath.

So my questions are:

- What do I do wrong?
- Can someone give a hint or an advice how to make it working?

### Spreadsheet table

```
| Audience Name | URL include 1 | URL include 2 | URL include 3 | URL exclude 1 | URL exclude 2 | URL exclude 3 | Duration |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|----------|
| Test 1        | /test         | /test2        |               |               |               |               | 540      |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|----------|
| Test 2        | /test3        | /test4        |               |               |               |               | 540      |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|----------|
```

### Spreadsheet macro script

```js
function main() {

  var settings = {'linkedView':"XXXXXXXXX",
                  'linkedAccountId':"XXX-XXX-XXXX",
                  'accountId':'XXXXXXXX',
                  'propertyID':'UA-XXXXXXXX-X'};

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('XXXXXX');
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('test');
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 8);
  var values = range.getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var name = values[i][0];
    var categoryUrl = values[i][1];
    var duration = Math.floor(values[i][7]);

    Logger.log(duration);

    var inludeSegment = '';
    var exludeSegment = '';

    if(values[i][1]) {
      inludeSegment += 'users::condition::ga:pagePath=@'+ values[i][1];
    }
    /*
    if(values[i][2]) {
      inludeSegment += ';ga:pagePath==' + values[i][2];
    }

    if(values[i][3]) {
      inludeSegment += ';ga:pagePath==' + values[i][3];
    }

    if(values[i][4]) {
      exludeSegment += 'sessions::condition::ga:pagePath==' + values[i][4];
    }

    if(values[i][5]) {
      exludeSegment += ';ga:pagePath==' + values[i][5];
    }

    if(values[i][6]) {
      exludeSegment += ';ga:pagePath==' + values[i][6];
    }*/

    var newAudience = Analytics.Management.RemarketingAudience.insert(
      {
        'name': name,
        'linkedViews': [settings.linkedView],
        'linkedAdAccounts': [{
            'type': 'ADWORDS_LINKS',
            'linkedAccountId': settings.linkedAccountId,
        }],
        'description' : 'test',
        'audienceType': 'SIMPLE',
        'audienceDefinition': {
          'includeConditions': {
            'daysToLookBack': 14,
            'segment': inludeSegment,
            'membershipDurationDays': duration,
            'isSmartList': false
          }
        }
      },
    settings.accountId,
    settings.propertyID
    );

    Logger.log(newAudience);

   Logger.log(i + ' Audience ' + name + ' has been created');
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have issue with segments definition.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments-feature-reference

This article helps you.

Because when you use ';' between pagePathes it means session must include both. 
users::condition::ga:pagePath=@/category1;ga:pagePath=@/category2

This segment will collect all user who are visit **2 categories**.

If we using ','
users::condition::ga:pagePath=@/category1**,**ga:pagePath=@/category2

This segment will collect all users from 1 and 2 categories, even user has visited only one.

you should use '!' To exclude something from segment

sessions::condition::**!**ga:exitPagePath==/

Hope it helps you!